# Compare years in Cognos RS - Outer join not working

Tags: report, cognos

I want to create a crosstab where on the y-axis there are the months and on the x-axis is the previous year and the current year.

```
                   2011  |  2012
Shop_1  |  Jan  |  123   |  456
           Feb  |  789   |  1011
           ...  |  ...   |  ...
           Dez  |  234   |  454  (for the current year, the future months are either filled with predicted numbers or NULL)
----------------------------------
Shop_2  |  Jan  |  264   |  23409
           ...  |  ...   |  ...
           Dez  |  234   |  454
```

The data source is relational, so I created two query items for each year, in SQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
shop, month, numberOfOrders 
FROM myFactTable 
INNER JOIN Dim_date ...
INNER JOIN Dim_shop ...
WHERE Dim_date.year = 2012
```

Then I join those 2 queries with 3 connections.

- year2012query.Shop  `=` year2011query.Shop
- year2012query.Month `=` year2011query.Month
- year2012query.Year  `>` year2011query.Year

and set the cardinality to 0..n on both sides making it an `outer join`. I have tried any other possibility with the cardinality, but nothing works. Problem is, I only get the months up to April, the current month. So the `OUTER JOIN` is not working.

So I was thinking, that the cardinality in my Framework Manager model might play a role. It's a star schema and the cardinality is always

```
Dimension Table <--> Fact Table
1..1                 1..n
```

Changing this to

```
Dimension Table <--> Fact Table
1..1                 0..n
```

just had the effect that the report performance becomes unacceptable and the result is weird:

```
                   2011  |  2012
           Apr  |        |
           May  |        |
           Jun  |        |
           ...  |        |
           Dez  |        |
----------------------------------
Shop_1  |  Jan  |  123   |  456
           Feb  |  789   |  1011
           Mar  |  123   |  123
           Apr  |  234   |  454  
----------------------------------
Shop_2  |  Jan  |  264   |  23409
           Feb  |  7123  |  1011
           Mar  |  1223  |  123
           Apr  |  3445  |  454
```

How can I achieve, that the full last year is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it on my own. The cardinality in the FM model remains untouched

```
Dimension (1..1) <--> (1..n) Fact
```

My mistake was to select the months of the current year when joining the queries for the current and the past year.